# ZFS: zpool import - UNAVAIL missing device

Tags: debian, zfs

For about a year I had a debian server running with data on dm-crypt/ luks-encrypted hdds underneath zfs (pool name zdata), 8 hdds in a mirrored mode, so 4 mirrors with 2 hdds each.
A zpool status from the healthy times:

```
# zpool status  
pool: zdata  
state: ONLINE  
scrub: scrub completed after (blahblah)  
config:  
NAME        STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM  
zdata          ONLINE       0     0     0  
mirror-0       ONLINE       0     0     0  
 dm-name-n8_2  ONLINE       0     0     0  
 dm-name-n8_3  ONLINE       0     0     0  
mirror-1       ONLINE       0     0     0  
 dm-name-n8_0  ONLINE       0     0     0  
 dm-name-n8_1  ONLINE       0     0     0  
mirror-2       ONLINE       0     0     0  
 dm-name-n8_4  ONLINE       0     0     0  
 dm-name-n8_5  ONLINE       0     0     0  
mirror-3       ONLINE       0     0     0  
 dm-name-n8_7  ONLINE       0     0     0  
 dm-name-n8_6  ONLINE       0     0     0  
errors: No known data errors
```

(Of course, no backup of this 34TB raw data. I can give up on almost all data, but there are some files I consider precious to me.)
Two weeks ago after upgrading to stable I noticed several read, write and checksum errors beginning with dm-name-n8_2. A scrub didn't do it, because zfs began a resilvering, but never ended it, as it began over and over again. That was the moment, where also dm-name-n8_3, the other hdd in this mirror, showed same kind of errors and I began to realize, that both hhds respectively their controllers were dying.
I think, than I did silly things, not everything I can comprehend at the moment (*zpool history* shows nothing). Among others I initiated a replace with the "better" disks. In the meantime I worked on a defect home appliance which caused a power outage, and after booting up I wasn't able to import the pool again.
The bad disks are now dd'ed and substituted.
Eventually I cannot import the pool again:

```
# zpool import -f
pool: zdata
id: 1343310357846896221
state: UNAVAIL
status: One or more devices were being resilvered.
action: The pool cannot be imported due to damaged devices or data.
config:

zdata             UNAVAIL  missing device
mirror-0        DEGRADED
 dm-name-n8_2  UNAVAIL
 dm-name-n8_3  ONLINE
mirror-1       ONLINE
 n8_0          ONLINE
 n8_1          ONLINE
mirror-2       DEGRADED
 dm-name-n8_4  ONLINE
 dm-name-n8_5  UNAVAIL
mirror-3       ONLINE
 n8_7          ONLINE
 dm-name-n8_6  ONLINE

# zpool import zdata -f
cannot import 'zdata': one or more devices is currently unavailable
```

Samesame with *zpool import zdata -fnF*
Note the changed device names.
The pool has at least *one* device online in each mirror, why does it complain about a missing device?
How do I get to know, which device is missing? Are there ways to get the pool online again and how do I do it?
(I read the oracle docs and the chapter on zfs at the freebsd handbook, learned some things, but didn't find an answer to my questions.)
The output from zdb is a bit lengthy, it can be seen [here](http://nopaste.debianforum.de/39930).

Comment: Try using `zpool status -P`, it will show you the unavailable device absolute paths.

Comment: @CMCDragonkai: (cannot format sufficiently here, sorry) thanks for help, but na, that doesn't work: # zpool status -P  no pools available

Comment: Try using with `sudo`.

Comment: @CMCDragonkaiYepp, I did all this as root. `zfs` and `zpool` commands need root.

Answer (score 2):

Eventually I found a solution for the mess:
I saw differing `status`messages dependent on which disks I took to bring the pool up again.
I made several attempts to import the pool in a degraded state with various combinations of four corresponding disks, and in the end I got this:

```
NAME                       STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
zdata                      DEGRADED     0     0     0
  mirror-0                 DEGRADED     0     0     0
    dm-name-n8_2           ONLINE       0     0     0  (resilvering)
    11141007683912581709   UNAVAIL      0     0     0  was     /dev/disk/by-id/dm-name-n8_3
  mirror-1                 DEGRADED     0     0     0
    16620393607066428577   FAULTED      0     0     0  was     /dev/disk/by-id/dm-name-n8_0
    dm-name-n8_0           ONLINE       0     0     0
  mirror-2                 DEGRADED     0     0     0
    replacing-0            DEGRADED    85     0     0
      1051730541091272780  FAULTED      0     0     0  was     /dev/disk/by-id/dm-name-n8_4
      dm-name-n8_6         ONLINE       0     0    85  (resilvering)
dm-name-n8_4           ONLINE       0     0     0  (resilvering)
  mirror-3                 DEGRADED     0     0     0
    dm-name-n8_5           ONLINE       0     0     0
    13833275275194605312   FAULTED      0     0     0  was     /dev/disk/by-id/dm-name-n8_6
```

which enabled me to scrape almost all data from the damaged disks. The loss was about ~0.1% (134 of >70000) files.

From my understanding, zfs stores configuration data at each device of that pool, and keeps them synchronized. Maybe the power outage damaged this, or the dying disks?

Anyway, I am happy again. Thanks for reading and helping!

Answer (score 0):

Just for future reference.
Putting I/O buffer (zfs) on top of different I/O buffer (HardWare RAID controller) is **always** a bad idea.
These two ignore each other and can/will cause all sorts of trouble.
The smart way to avoid this is to use network storage devices.